# Redshift: When is the data from an insert available for selecting?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a system that writes some rows to Redshift. As soon as it's done (using the JDBC, so as soon as the line of code finishes), we send an id to a queue and another system picks up this id and reads these rows and related rows from Redshift.

This reading usually happens in the same second. The problem is, about 10% of the time it can't find the data that was (apparently) just written. The data is definitely there. Reprocessing these items at a later date gains different (correct) results.

So, my question is does Redshift guarantee immediate data consistency or does our system simply have to wait before reading? And if it has to wait, for how long?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not consider the row written until you receive the confirmation from Redshift.

The time may depend on the cluster load, other writes to that table, etc.

Try waiting for success confirmation via JDBC before sending the id to your queue.

Comment: Unfortunately we do wait for confirmation from the JDBC. We just swapped redshift out for a standard postgres installation and everything's working as expected, with no code change at all.

Comment: Yep, why were you using Redshift for this originally?

Answer (score 0):

Once the changes have been committed they should be available, however, it's possible that the auto-commit behavior is causing some kind of delay between when your INSERT/UPDATE completes and the completion of the commit.

I would suggest making sure you wrap any database changes in a transaction and wait for the COMMIT to complete before messaging the other system you referenced.